# Django load is very slow

Tags: django, performance, filter

I am new in Django. one page of my web application load is very slow. I don't know where is the bottleneck.

there is my code:

model.py

```
class Fact_CarCase(models.Model):
    CaseCode = models.IntegerField()
    FraudulantRate = models.FloatField(null=True)
    FraudType = models.ForeignKey('Dim_FraudType', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    IssueUnit = models.ForeignKey('Dim_Units', to_field="UnitCode", related_name='Fact_CarCase_IssueUnit', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    AgentUnit = models.ForeignKey('Dim_Units', to_field="UnitCode", related_name='Fact_CarCase_AgentUnit', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    IncidentCity = models.ForeignKey('Dim_City', to_field="CityCode", related_name='Fact_CarCase_IncidentCity', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CaseUnit = models.ForeignKey('Dim_Units', to_field="UnitCode", related_name='Fact_CarCase_CaseUnit', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CaseDate = models.ForeignKey('Dim_Date', to_field="MasterDate", related_name='Fact_CarCase_CaseDate', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    IssueDate = models.ForeignKey('Dim_Date', to_field="MasterDate", related_name='Fact_CarCase_IssueUnitDate', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    LastEndosmentDate = models.ForeignKey('Dim_Date', to_field="MasterDate", related_name='Fact_CarCase_LastEndosmentDate', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    DriverType = models.ForeignKey('Dim_DriverType', to_field="DriverTypeCode", related_name='Fact_CarCase_DriverType', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    CarKind = models.ForeignKey('Dim_CarKind', to_field="CarKindCode", related_name='Fact_CarCase_CarKind', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    CompleteCause = models.ForeignKey('Dim_CompleteCause', to_field="CompleteCauseCode", related_name='Fact_CarCase_CompleteCause', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    CaseInspector = models.ForeignKey('Dim_CaseInspector', to_field="CaseInspectorCode", related_name='Fact_CarCase_CaseInspector', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=True)
    DraftAmount = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    CaseOfUsage = models.ForeignKey('Dim_CaseOfUsage', to_field="CaseOfUsageCode", related_name='Fact_CarCase_CaseOfUsage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    IncidentReason = models.ForeignKey('Dim_IncidentReason', to_field="IncidentReasonCode", related_name='Fact_CarCase_IncidentReason', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    CaseType = models.ForeignKey('Dim_CaseType', to_field="CaseTypeCode", related_name='Fact_CarCase_CaseType', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ReviewItems = models.ManyToManyField('Dim_ReviewItems', through='Middle_CaseReviewItems')
    FinalInsurerName = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    IncidentKind = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    IncidentDate = models.ForeignKey('Dim_Date', to_field="MasterDate", related_name='Fact_CarCase_IncidentDate', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    # FeedBack = models.ManyToManyField('Fact_FeedBack', through='Middle_CaseFeedBack')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.CaseCode)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        # return self.CaseUnit.UnitTitle
        return '{} در تاریخ {}'.format(self.CaseUnit.UnitTitle, self.CaseDate.MasterDate_Slash)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Dim_Units(models.Model):
    UnitCode = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    UnitTitle = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.UnitTitle

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Dim_IncidentReason(models.Model):
    IncidentReasonCode = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    IncidentReasonTitle = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.IncidentReasonTitle


.
.
.
```

Filters.py

```
class CaseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    CaseDate_Year__gte = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='CaseDate', lookup_expr='MasterYear__gte')
    CaseDate_Month__gte = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='CaseDate', lookup_expr='MasterMonth__gte')
    CaseDate_Day__gte = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='CaseDate', lookup_expr='MasterDay__gte')

    CaseDate_Year__lte = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='CaseDate', lookup_expr='MasterYear__lte')
    CaseDate_Month__lte = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='CaseDate', lookup_expr='MasterMonth__lte')
    CaseDate_Day__lte = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='CaseDate', lookup_expr='MasterDay__lte')

    FraudulantRate__gte = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='FraudulantRate', lookup_expr='gte')
    FraudulantRate__lte = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='FraudulantRate', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Fact_CarCase
        fields = ['CaseType']
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def search(request):
    case_list = models.Fact_CarCase.objects.all()
    case_filter = filters.CaseFilter(request.GET, queryset=case_list)
    return render(request, 'CarIA/user_list.html', {'filter': case_filter})
```

template:

```
.
.
.

<div class="mypopup"  id="myForm">
  <form method="get">
    <div style="text-align:right;padding-right:8px;color:#303A43;font-size:14px;">فیلترها </div>

    <!--++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
            <div>
        <div>
        <label class="quti"  style="position:absolute;top:36px;right:16px;font-size:12px;color: #92A6B6;">از تاریخ</label>

    <div>
      <input type="number" name="CaseDate_Day__gte" step="any" id="id_CaseDate_Day__gte"
      style="top:58px;left:223px;position:absolute;width:47px;height:36px;border: 1px solid #CCDDEB;border-radius: 4px;opacity: 1;font-size:14px;
                letter-spacing: 0;color: #303A43;opacity: 1;text-align: center;float:right;direction:rtl;">
    </div>


    <script>
          var CaseDate_gte = document.getElementById("id_CaseDate_Year__gte").value
                            +document.getElementById("id_CaseDate_Month__gte").value
                            +document.getElementById("id_CaseDate_Day__gte").value;
    </script>


            <div style="width:60px;height:22px;color: #CCDDEB;font-size:19px;position:absolute;top:58px;left:210px;">/</div>


        <div>
          <input type="number" name="CaseDate_Month__gte" step="any" id="id_CaseDate_Month__gte" class="months">
        </div>


      <div style="width:6px;height:22px;color: #CCDDEB;font-size:19px;position:absolute;top:58px;left:93px;">/</div>

      <div>
        <input type="number" name="CaseDate_Year__gte" step="any" id="id_CaseDate_Year__gte" class="years">
      </div>


        </div>

    <div>
        <label class="quti" style="position:absolute;top:105px;right:16px;font-size:12px;color: #92A6B6;">تا تاریخ</label>


    <div>
      <input type="number" name="CaseDate_Day__lte" step="any" id="id_CaseDate_Day__lte" class="enddays">
    </div>

        <div style="width:6px;height:22px;color: #CCDDEB;font-size:19px;position:absolute;top:133px;left:210px;">/</div>

    <div>
      <input type="number" name="CaseDate_Month__lte" step="any" id="id_CaseDate_Month__lte" class="endmonths">
    </div>

        <div style="width:6px;height:22px;color: #CCDDEB;font-size:19px;position:absolute;top:133px;left:93px;">/</div>

    <div>
      <input type="number" name="CaseDate_Year__lte" step="any" id="id_CaseDate_Year__lte" class="endyears">
    </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->

    <div>
        <label for="incidentTypes" class="quti" style="position:absolute;top:181px;right:16px;font-size:12px;color: #92A6B6;">نوع پرونده</label>


    <select name="CaseType" id="id_CaseType" style="top:202px;right:16px;font-family:IRANSans;" class="vorudi">

      {% for obj in filter.form.fields.CaseType.choices %}
          <option value="{{ obj.0 }}"> {{ obj.1 }} </option>
      {% endfor %}

    </select>

        </div>




<div>
        <label for="cities" class="quti" style="top:258px;right:16px;font-size:12px;color: #92A6B6;position:absolute;">واحد پرونده</label>
    <select name="CaseType" id="id_CaseType" style="top:279px;right:16px;font-family:IRANSans;" class="vorudi">

      {% for obj in filter.form.fields.CaseUnit.choices %}
          <option value="{{ obj.0 }}"> {{ obj.1 }} </option>
      {% endfor %}

    </select>
    </div>



    <div>
        <label for="fraudTypes" class="quti" style="top:335px;right:16px;font-size:12px;color: #92A6B6;position:absolute;">واحد صدور</label>
    <select name="CaseType" id="id_CaseType" style="top:356px;right:16px;font-family:IRANSans;" class="vorudi">

      {% for obj in filter.form.fields.IssueUnit.choices %}
          <option value="{{ obj.0 }}"> {{ obj.1 }} </option>
      {% endfor %}

    </select>

    </div>

    <div style="position:absolute;top:410px;width:293px;right:16px;">
         <p style="text-align: right;font-size:12px;letter-spacing: 0;color: #92A6B6;;margin-bottom:0;">مشکوک بودن</p>

    <input type="range" name="weight" style="width:88%;" id="range_weight" value="5" min="1" max="100" oninput="range_weight_disp.value=range_weight.value">
    <output id="range_weight_disp"></output>


        </div>


    <button type="submit" style="position:absolute;top:458px;margin-top:24px;width: 325px;height: 48px;background: #00559A 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;border:none;font-size:18px;color:white;font-family:IRANSans;" onclick="closeForm()">اعمال فیلتر</button>

  </form>
</div>

.
.
.



<div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="scrollTable" style="font-family:IRANSans;">
<thead class="fixedHeader">
<tr>
<th width="90px" style="border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 0px;"> مشکوک بودن</th>
<th width="90px">نوع پرونده</th>
<th width="90px">واحد پرونده</th>
<th width="90px">واحد صدور</th>
<th width="90px">بیمه گزار</th>
<th width="90px">تاریخ پرونده</th>
<th width="90px" style="border-radius: 0px 8px 0px 0px;">کد پرونده</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="scrollContent" style="font-family:IRANSans;">
{% for r in filter.qs %}
<tr style="font-family:IRANSans;">
<td width="200px" style="font-family:IRANSans;">{{r.FraudulantRate}}</td>
<td width="200px" style="font-family:IRANSans;">{{r.CaseType}}</td>
<td width="200px" style="font-family:IRANSans;">{{r.CaseUnit}}</td>
<td width="200px" style="font-family:IRANSans;">{{r.IssueUnit}}</td>
<td width="200px" style="font-family:IRANSans;">{{r.FinalInsurerName}}</td>
<td width="200px" style="font-family:IRANSans;">{{r.CaseDate}}</td>
<td width="200px"><a style="font-family:IRANSans;font-size:14px;" href="{% url 'caria_CaseDetail' r.id %}">{{r.CaseCode}}</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

.
.
.
```

Database records are about 2000. and will take about 20 to 30 seconds to load. How can I improve the performance problem?

any suggestions would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, investigate why the page load is slow. The [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is userful for this.

You'll probably see that you have queries for the foreign keys for each row (the n+1 query problem).

You can use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to select the related objects to prevent these extra queries.

```
case_list = models.Fact_CarCase.objects.all().select_related('CaseDate', 'CaseType')
```

This will stop extra queries for `CaseDate`and `CaseType`, but look through your template or the SQL queries in debug toolbar to see which other foreign keys you have to add to the list.

Comment: Thank you. There was countless queries problem And resolved with "Select_related".